# Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm having trouble dynamically allocating memory for an array. I've been debugging for hours, any pointers?

I posted the rest of the code. It is simply supposed to exchange the swap the first row with the second, and the third with the forth. I am getting strange results like:

Enter string: hello

Enter string: how are you

Enter string: i'm good thanks

Enter string: bye

Enter string: bai

Enter string: xx

=========================

how are you

!i'm good thanks

hello

!how are you

bye

!bai

i'm good thanks

!bye

bai

!xx

```
    int count = 0;
    char *lines[MAX_LINES];
    char *tmp[50]; 


    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(tmp, 50, stdin);
    lines[count] = (char *) malloc((strlen(tmp)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(lines[count], tmp); 

    while(strcmp("xx\n", lines[count])){
            count++;
            printf("Enter string: ");
            fgets(tmp, 50, stdin); 
            lines[count] = (char *) malloc((strlen(tmp)+1)* sizeof(char));

            strcpy(lines[count], tmp); 
    }

void exchange(char * records[])
{
    char * temp;
    temp = records[0];
    records[0] = records[1];
    records[1] = temp;

    temp = records[2];
    records[2] = records[3];
    records[3] = temp; 

}

void printArray(char * inputs[], int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
            printf("%c", inputs[i][j]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice pun :)... also ROFL!

Comment: However, in all seriousness, can you tell us what exactly your problem is?

Comment: @Jashaszun The pun was certainly unintended.

Comment: Good pun ;)  Q: What exactly is the problem?  Q: Have you been able to isolate it to a specific line?  Q: Are you debugging with a debugger (e.g. gdb or Visual Studio)?

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about type mismatches in the call to `fgets()` because `tmp` should be `char tmp[50];`.

Comment: I posted the rest of my code. I have no idea where the problem is :(

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_LINES = 50 };
static void printArray(char *inputs[], int rows);
static int readLine(char *buffer, size_t buflen);

int main(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    char *lines[MAX_LINES];
    char  tmp[50]; 

    for (count = 0; count < MAX_LINES; count++)
    {
        if (readLine(tmp, sizeof(tmp)) == EOF)
            break;
        lines[count] = (char *) malloc((strlen(tmp)+1)* sizeof(char));
        if (lines[count] == 0)
            break;
        strcpy(lines[count], tmp); 
    }

    putchar('\n');
    printArray(lines, count);

    return(0);
}

static int read_line(char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    printf("Enter string: ");
    if (fgets(buffer, buflen, stdin) == 0 || strcmp("xx\n", buffer) == 0)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

static void printArray(char *inputs[], int rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        printf("%d: %s", i, inputs[i]);
}
```

Sample run 1 (using EOF):

```
$ ./rl
Enter string: Abyssinia
Enter string: Wimbledon Common
Enter string: ^D
0: Abyssinia
1: Wimbledon Common
$
```

Sample run 2 (using '`xx`'):

```
$ ./rl
Enter string: Abyssinia
Enter string: Wimbledon Common
Enter string: Strawberry Lemonade
Enter string: xx

0: Abyssinia
1: Wimbledon Common
2: Strawberry Lemonade
$
```

What's different?  I fixed the type on `tmp` as noted in a comment.  I created a function `readLine()` to manage the prompt and read and compare with `"xx\n"` process to avoid repetition.  I avoided using `strdup()` but do check that `malloc()` succeeds before using the pointer returned.  I ensure that there are not too many lines read in (the `for` loop).  The `printArray()` code only takes the number of rows because the strings are of varying length.  I removed the `exchange()` function since it was not being used and I couldn't see how it was supposed to be used.  The code is complete and compilable (so it is an SSCCE — [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).